# Problem with ''Split lines by points''

Tags: qgis

I'm trying to use the SAGA tool ''split Lines by points''.
I have created the  line layer using '' Polygon to lines''

[image: the lines layer]

My goal is to split the lines. I created points using Extract points

[image]

I want to have new lines based on those points. I tried to use ''split lines by points'' but then I get something like this

[image]

I have changed the epsilon but it still has the same problem.

**My end goal is to have ''independent'' lines that I can divide into segments of 12.5 meters**.

Comment: Please refrain from writing in ALL CAPS. It's the online equivalent of shouting and will often lead to your question being down-voted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your end goal is just to have the polygon boundaries broken up into line segments, the `Explode lines` tool will do that.

> This algorithm takes a lines layer and creates a new one in which each line is replaced by a set of lines representing the segments in the original line. Each line in the resulting layer contains only a start and an end point, with no intermediate nodes between them.

If that doesn't work, see below for a workaround to the issue with the SAGA tool.

---

That's a common issue with the SAGA tool `split lines by points`. Here's a workaround:

1. Use `geometry by expression` to create a temporary layer of lines. Use the split points as the input layer, and use a geometry expression like this:

   ```
   make_line($geometry, make_point($x+1, $y))
   ```

   The output should be a temporary layer of very short lines that start at the split points, and extend a very short distance due east.
2. Check the output and make sure the lines don't cross any of your original lines more than once. If they do, re-do the first step with a smaller x-offset value (eg `make_point($x+0.0001, $y)`).
3. Use these lines in the QGIS tool `split with lines` to split the original line layer.

Comment: by temporary layer do your mean virtual layer? If so, could you provide code example how to create such layer? I used the code in my splitting point layer but that cannot be used as input layer in `split with lines`. Not sure what I am missing. I am facing same problem here.

Comment: He meant geometry by expression, which you can find in Processing Algorithms. It takes your input geometry and creates lines from your point layer, so that you can use Split Lines With Lines instead of points which provides better results.